# Unable to change DNS resolver to localhost

Tags: python, sockets, dns, udp

I configured my windows machine's DNS server to `127.0.0.1` and on localhost I created a basic `python server`:

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 53
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', serverPort))
print "The server is ready to receive on port: {}".format(serverPort)
while 1:
    try:
        message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(512)
    except:
        continue
    print clientAddress, message
    modifiedMessage = "127.0.0.1"
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

***PS*** :I know that DNS is a binary protocol and sending ASCII text won't do any good, but I am not trying to make a resolver, I am trying to see with transperancy that how the former works.

When I srarted the server, I am greated with the following output:

```
(('127.0.0.1', 53945), '.\x9c\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
(('127.0.0.1', 53945), '.\x9c\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
(('127.0.0.1', 53945), '.\x9c\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
(('127.0.0.1', 61362), '\xefc\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
(('127.0.0.1', 50065), '\xb5\xfc\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
(('127.0.0.1', 61362), '\xefc\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
(('127.0.0.1', 61362), '\xefc\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
(('127.0.0.1', 52718), '\xc7\x15\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05tiles\x08services\x07mozilla\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01')
```

But unlike as I enticipated, I am still able to open websites. And Wireshark told me that I am making connection to `8.8.8.8`(IDK how?).
I tried flushing the DNS cashe from my machine, nada.
What am I missing?

***PPS:*** If I remove the `try/catch` clause I get this error(a few seconds *after* the execution of the program):

```
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: have you restarted the machine after changing the settings? Do you see requests to localhost before the same requests are repeated using google dns servers? You could run `tshark -i any port 53`, to see dns requests (`tshark` is a command-line client for Wireshark).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes I restarted the machine. I wasn't able to comprehend the second part. And `tshark -i any port 53`, a command(I am confused cause of `any port` part)?

Comment: As I said, the purpose of the command is to see all DNS requests. If you want to know what individual command-line parameters do; [read tshark's man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have configured Googles `8.8.8.8` as a fallback DNS server.

And since you are destroying the DNS answers, whoever is receiving these broken answers is falling back to the secondary server. The whole path of DNS queries on a typical UN*X machine is quite complicated and the whole system is usually quite robust.

Comment: I am using windows machine. 
Is there any way to prevent them from using a fallback server?

Comment: also, the output, it's using name-compression right?